# Fetch all Email address of facebook user in android

Tags: android

i m creating application in which i have to obtain friend list of facebook user account which i got but now i have to also obtain their Email addresses but not getting any kind of hint , tell me how can i fetch all Email addresses of facebook users in android

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Its not possible cause Facebook API doensn't provide it.

From Experience:
You can search and read a bit more in Facebook Graph API permission and you will find for contact information need to give extra permission "email" but while fetching user acoounts of Friends you wont get them even if they(friends) have set their info shared to everyone.

Comment: it possible through graph Api goto this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: but i am not getting graph Api to fetch fb contacts is their any hint ?